# Why is CSS "*:not(textarea)" not getting everything except textarea to disable selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this simple demo setup:

https://jsfiddle.net/9rsu7vnq/

```
<div>something</div>
<textarea>asdasdasd</textarea>

*:not(textarea){
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

NOTE that for the jsfiddle test, you will first have to click on the white area with the rendered output before doing Ctrl+A

I was expecting `*:not(textarea)` to basically disable selection (using ctrl+A) for everything except `textarea`. So in this example, the `textarea` would still be selected but div shouldn't. But that's not what's happening. It disables selection on everything including the textarea.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using Chromium 89 based browser and for me everything works fine

Comment: @Maciej Bledkowski Can you click outside of the textarea and still select the contents inside when using ctrl + a? Because that shouldn't work.

Comment: @MircoS. No, I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the used css selector also affects the surrounding elements like body and html. If you exclude them it works:

```
*:not(textarea *):not(body):not(html) {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrd3w4qe/1/

Edit 2: apparently only working in chromium based browsers.

Comment: May i ask what the downvote is for? If you take this fiddle for example https://jsfiddle.net/Lrd3w4qe/1/ click outside of the textarea and then press ctrl+a it works exactly as wished while this is not the case for the given example in the question https://jsfiddle.net/8b3dzygu/1/?

Comment: I didn't downvote you and wish whoever did should have left a comment. However, your answer doesn't work for me. It didn't make any change. When I try Ctrl+A on yours, it still doesn't let me select.

Comment: I should have added that i just tested it in chrome. Which browser did you use?

Comment: You are right. I was using Safari. I tested all 3 and it only works on Chrome. Firefox and Safari both don't select anything. Any idea why? Here's an example with 4 elements: https://jsfiddle.net/6boayrcd/

Comment: In firefox it just seems not possible to select anything with ctrl + a when being outside of a textarea, even without any css. No idea for safari and no possibility to test it on safari right now. You could try removing the '*' in the first not() https://jsfiddle.net/w45Lgnjm/6/

Comment: Yea you are right. Seems like Firefox only allows textarea selection if it's in focus. I will switch to using javascript `keydown` event to select everything as needed on Ctrl+A key. I will accept your answer and give you an upvote to cancel out whoever downvoted it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `not(textarea *)` means "any element that is not a descendant of a <textarea>", since textarea can only have text as content, this also means "any element". Kinda useless... And @PranoyC, you utltimately deal with your votes as you wish, but voting for anything else than the post value is frowned upon, as is accepting an answer that did not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable your field if you don't need that user selected it

```
<textarea disabled>asdasdasd</textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

see the below example that's having two div, it works exactly the same way you expected from your code

```css
div{
  user-select: none;
}

#selectable {
  user-select: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>should not be selected while clicking ctrl+a</div>
<textarea id="selectable">Should be selected</textarea>
```

Comment: That’s not true. If you go to my jsfiddle from my post and comment out the css, then run and try to select, it will select both the div and textarea even if textarea isn’t focussed.

Comment: you are right, but I got it, why were you not getting the expected result, since you have used * that means the whole html document user-select got none, and textarea is a child tag of html hence it was not selected, see the above example it works now.